# DesiredCapabilities object not getting its properties

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the DesiredCapabilities in selenium for one of my project. I have created a new project and imported selenium standalone jars along with libs (tried this with 2.44 and 2.45 versions). Then I have written the below code,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

 public class DesiredCapaTest {

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.

 }
```

when I write the 'capabilities.' I expect to see different options like Set etc. However I am seeing a message 'Unavailable-bsh.Capabilities'. The same code is working fine in my office machine.

My home machine is Windows 8.1 and Office machine is Windows 7, not sure whether this matter. Awaiting your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Thank you all for your suggestions. I resolved the issue by installing the latest version of Eclipse and creating a new Workspace. I still don't have any clue why it didn't work with the setup I was using earlier.

Answer (score 0):

here is a comprehensive guide for the class.
https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/DesiredCapabilities.html

maybe you didn't tried the right methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

The function list is not displayed when you do **not** have the jar file: selenium-java-2.43.0.jar added to the build path of the project.

Please make sure you have all the jar files added to your build path.

1. Right click on your project->Build Path->Configure Build Path
2. Goto Libraries->Add External jar files
3. Add all the jar files made available with Selenium (please check bsh-1.3.0.jar as well)

Comment: I have already added the jars to the build path and bsh-1.3.0 jar is listed in External jars. As i mentioned in the post, the same is working fine in my office machine, problem is happening with my home machine.

Comment: How about this setting of Eclipse?   Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced - >Restore defaults...

Answer (score 0):

You should declare DesiredCapablities object inside the method if using TestNg or inside the public static void main method when using a standalone java class. 
The code for TestNG file is as under:

```
public class TestNGFile {
public String baseurl = "http://newtours.com/";
public WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

@Test(priority = 0)
public void Test1() {

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue as no suggestions for object of Desired Capabilities. I just closed all tabs (Sonarlint, TestNG etc) and just tried it again. it worked for me.